# Unable to copy .zip file created by an Azure Pipeline to a local PC folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to create a release azure pipeline that compresses a downloaded artifact (.zip file) directly on a local PC folder and then copy it into another.
I run the release pipeline and it completes successfully, but both folders are empty.

[Release pipeline overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm2hs.png)

Here's an example of one run logs:

- [Download Artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SklWY.png)
- [Download Pipeline Artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WkY2.png)
- [Archive Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHCsk.png)
- [Copy Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylo3I.png)

I tried to see if the file is hidden but I didn't find it. I also checked the permissions of both folders and 'Everyone' has full control on them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED:**

The problem was that the release pipeline was running on AzureDevOps agent.
After creating a self-hosted agent everything works properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Download Pipeline Artifact task is not needed.  When you choose an artifact in the classic release pipeline, it will auto add a Download artifact task (this [image] task in your release pipeline) and download the artifacts to `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`(Same as `Agent.ReleaseDirectory` and `System.ArtifactsDirectory`). So, you can delete the Download Pipeline Artifact task.
2. `Pipeline.Workspace` is not a variable for the classic release pipeline. It is mentioned in the tips of [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#pipeline-variables-devops-services). So, you can use the `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` in the Archive files task.

> If you are using classic release pipelines, you can use classic releases and artifacts variables to store and access data throughout your pipeline.

The modified Archive files task:

[image]

The modified Copy files task:

[image]

My test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, the `Pipeline.Workspace` variable only works in YAML-based pipelines, not "classic" pipelines or "releases". You probably want `Agent.ReleaseDirectory` instead. [Relevant docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables)